# MySQL Export to Excel Writes Whole PHP File

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, excel

I am having an issue where when I go to write a MySQL table to an Excel file using PHP it writes the table, but then also writes the whole HTML document.

Here is the code I'm using to write Excel document:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   include("connection.php");
   $filename = "list.csv"; 

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
   header("Expires: 0");

   $fileData = "SELECT * FROM `Table` ORDER BY `Name`;";
   $info = $conn->query($fileData);

   $flag = false;
   while ($the_row = $info->fetch_assoc()) {
       if (!$flag) {
           echo implode(",", array_keys($the_row)) . "\r\n";
           $flag = true;
       }
       echo implode(",", array_values($the_row)) . "\r\n";
   }

   mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

I only want the file to export on button click, and it does export the table perfectly. Just not sure why it is also doing the whole html document.

Here is the HTML for the submit:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <button class="btn right" type="submit" name="submit">Export List</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the html code where you `submit` also

Comment: @Isaac I have updated the question with that code

Comment: If you're exporting to a csv file use `fputcsv()`, it does most of the job of exporting for you. Here's a link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: The MIME type for CSV is `text/csv`. A faux header will not magically convert the output into a real Excel document.

Comment: _"why it is also doing the whole html document"_ - Is your PHP code in the top of your HTML page? Then you need to add an `exit;` in the line after `mysqli_close($conn);` or the script will continue outputting the HTML that comes after.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes! That was it! I knew it had to be something like that, hence closing the sql connection. Thank you!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson beat me to it!:P pop it into an answer so we can chuck you some rep!:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to put an answer here so no one else tries to answer this anymore. an `exit` needs to be added after you `mysqli_close($conn)` otherwise this is why it'll output the html